# How to debug an exe

Tags: eclipse

I am running a web application code from Eclipse. I have to run an exe and work on that.[Loading of the page in the web browser will not work.] 
I would like to debug the code, As for Java side I can able to debug it after running the exe. But I could not debug the UI part. I looked into the internet and have come to know that we can debug it in visual studio. 
I tried to open the exe file in visual studio and placed some breakpoints in the JS and started both the server and the exe in debug mode but still it is not working. Please let me know what i am doing wrong or is there any other way where I can able to debug the code.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: You can't debug an exe. You can only debug the program, which has been compiled into the mentioned exe.

Comment: Thanks for you r reply and sorry, Updated my last line. As you have mentioned i would like to debug the code, but i cannot debug the UI part. Any changes made to the UI part is not getting reflected in it as well.